# Extending Cloudfoundry's UAA functionality

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, war, cloud-foundry, cloudfoundry-uaa

We want to use `UAA` as an oauth2 provider for our services, but some of functionalities should changed or reconfigured to meet our needs. (Mostly involves rebranding and tweaking some of workflows)

Now my question is how we can achieve this?
My current solution is as follows: use `cloudfoundry-identity-uaa` as a `war` dependency in a new `war` project and then overwrite or add `spring` xml config files and add other classes needed to `war`.
Is there any better approach?

**Edit:**
Some of my desired changes:
 1. Change Signup Workflow in order to an admin verifies a new user instead of using email verification
 2. Change config of `TemplateResolver`s to enable `utf-8` templates
 3. Disable `csrf` protection on some of endpoints

Comment: What exactly is your use case where you need to override UAA ?

Comment: @11thdimension please view my edit

Comment: I'm not aware of signup functionality or email verification provided by UAA. Can you share the link ?

Comment: see e.g. https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa/blob/master/docs/UAA-APIs.rst#verify-user-get-users-id-verify for user verification

Answer (score 0):

Please find my answers inline

Some of my desired changes:
1. Change Signup Workflow in order to an admin verifies a new user instead of using email verification

We support disabling the end user sign up links on the login page. You can do this by setting the login.self_service_links_enabled property.

We don't have an admin interface for user management. This functionality has already been exposed via the [CF UAAC](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-uaac).

You can choose to code your admin flow based on the API's exposed for user account creation and password management.

2. Change config of TemplateResolvers to enable utf-8 templates

I would recommend that you create a issue under the [UAA github repo](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa/issues) so that we can get this incorporated into the standard product.

3. Disable csrf protection on some of endpoints

UAA is secure by default we have CSRF protection enabled for all end points.
Can you please elaborate on the use case for disabling this? Again, please raise a github issue so that we can track it.

Comment: We chose to code our flow based on APIs but some of endpoints are not very friendly for consumption through code, for example _Reset Password_ is designed to accessed from Browser and when we want to call it from our code `csrf` protection gets in our way.

Comment: I opened an issue in github regarding point 2: [#347](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa/issues/347)